# Why does this only work in php myadmin but not in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why does the following work when I paste it into phpmyadmin, however if I try and run the query using php it doesn't?

```
$sql="BEGIN;
INSERT INTO nodes (admin_id,title)
VALUES (1,'test');
INSERT INTO themes (theme_id,directory)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'test');
COMMIT;";
$sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
```

It is something to do with the LAST_INSERT_ID()... But I don't know what?!

Comment: It's probably that you're using multiple statements.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Does it throw errors? Change `mysql_query($sql);` to `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to find out.

Comment: Are you sure your connection has been established to the proper database and is valid?

Comment: You cant run multiple statement at the same time by mysql_query

Comment: Thansk silentboy, that sounds about right, so how do you do it?

Comment: http://www.php.net/mysql_query tells you everything you need to know to solve this problem. "Do not use this function". That and *mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)*.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run multiple queries within [mysql_query](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). So you would have to break it up

```
mysql_query('BEGIN');
mysql_query('INSERT INTO nodes (admin_id,title) VALUES (1,"test")');
$id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query('INSERT INTO themes (theme_id,directory) VALUES (' . $id . ', "test")');
mysql_query('COMMIT');
```

Please take note of the red box in the link. All these functions are **deprecated**.

Comment: Thanks Machavity, but does that not therefore begate the BEGIN and COMMIT, if they are all running separate queries?

Comment: Also would you all recommend mysqli? seeing as mysql functions all seem to be becoming deprecated?

Comment: Yes, you need to switch to `mysqli`. As to to the transaction, not it doesn't. Look at your original SQL. All those statements are separate queries. All I've done is break them up into something PHP can run.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the basic MySQL API for PHP does not support mulitiple queries in a single statement. Try using MySQLi instead, with respect to the following function:

> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php